# SQLAlchemy and query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to map this "simple" SQL-Statement into SQL-Alchemy

```
    select DISTINCT cv.*, ct."name"
    from "CarVariants" cv,
    "Cars" ca,
    "CarTypes" ct
    where cv."f_keyNumber" = ca."keyNumber"
    and cv."carType" = ca."carType"
    and cv."carType" = ct."f_carType"
    and "f_keyNumber" = '12345'
    and "f_carId" = 1
```

Something like this:

`variants = self.em.CarVariants.createQuery();`

`variants = variants.filter_by(f_keyNumber=12345, f_carId = 1).distinct()`

How do I add the "and"-relations (Cars, CarTypes) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `and_`

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
variants = variants.filter_by(and_(cond_1,cond_2....cond_n)).distinct()
```

See this page for further reference:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html